# Auto populate option tag not working java script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate number in select - option tag .But my script fills number at only one select tag

HTML :

```
 <div class="form_row">
       <label>Week Num</label>
       <select class="form_select1" id="weeknum"></select>
       <b class="bold1">&nbsp TO &nbsp</b>
       <select class="form_select1" id="weeknum1"></select>
 </div>
```

Javascript :

```
 <script>
   var select = document.getElementById("weeknum");
   var select1 = document.getElementById("weeknum1");
   for (var i = 52; i >= 1; i--) {
       var option = document.createElement('option');
       option.text = option.value = i;
       select.add(option, 0);
       select1.add(option, 0);
   }
</script>
```

[image]

How do i achieve that ?

Comment: see: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an element only once to a parent node, so you need to create another option element:

```
var select = document.getElementById("weeknum");
var select1 = document.getElementById("weeknum1");
for (var i = 52; i >= 1; i--) {
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.text = option.value = i;
   var option1 = document.createElement('option');
   option1.text = option1.value = i;
   select.add(option, 0);
   select1.add(option1, 0);
}
```

Here's the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55teLu3q/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
var option1 = document.createElement('option');
option1.text = option1.value = i;
select.add(option1, 0);
var option2 = document.createElement('option');
option2.text = option2.value = i;
select1.add(option2, 0);
```

... creating a distinct "option" for each select list.  The created elements cannot be reused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a distinct option element for each list. A given DOM element can only be in one place in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I see it's already answered... well, my first answer :)

try this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("weeknum"); 
var select1 = document.getElementById("weeknum1");

for (var i = 52; i >= 1; i--) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  var option1 = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = option.value =  option1.text = option1.value = i;
  select.add(option, 0);
  select1.add(option1, 0);
}
```